# Pathfinding optimization in a network

Tags: optimization, artificial-intelligence, modeling, path-finding, nonlinear-optimization

Actually I’m looking for some answers pointing me in the right direction and giving me some keywords to search and read in the right direction but I’m not sure if this is the right place to ask for it.
First I introduce the problem and then I explain what I’m looking for.

I have a couple of stations. Let’s say hospitals (S1, S2, S3). I have a couple of transportation wagons. Let’s say two cabs (C1, C2) and a couple of passengers. Let’s say three dudes (P1, P2, P3).
Each of the passengers has a different path through the hospitals with different times being treated there. But only one passenger can be treated at a place at the same time. So one have to wait for another to be finished at a place before he can start being treated there.

Passenger P1 wants to go to S1, S2, S3 and afterwards home (Which means essentially he is out of the game) He needs 100 minutes at every station.

Passenger P2 needs 30 minutes at every station.

And Passenger P3 needs 30 minutes at S2 and 100 Minutes at S3. He is skipping Station 1.

Also a cab can only carry one person at a time. The treating processes of course can happen parallel but only one at a place. Otherwise it wouldn’t be that difficult.

My problem is to find the perfect path (or near to perfect or at least good path) for the cabs to carry all the dudes around. Which means that all passengers should be treated in all there stations in the shortest total time. 
But my problems already begin in modelling the whole system properly. Right now I’m reading a couple of stuff about network optimization but I’m quite unsure if it’s the right direction.
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks a lot to machine scheduling to me.

Comment: Damn it i think that's exactly what i was looking for. Thank u so much. I needed just that word!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classical planning problem.  I use the word classical there specifically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just missed the right direction to go when i started. But after Erwin Kalvelagen droped the word scheduling and i googled it, i totally got the right direction to go. I just never heard about it before.